# What is the advantage of returning an object in a static function instead of building it?

Tags: c++, constructor, static-methods

Consider the following documentation of the Qt Framework as an example, even if my question is not Qt specific:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qversionnumber.html

You can find the static public member function:

```
QVersionNumber fromString(const QString &string, int *suffixIndex = nullptr)
```

instead of:

```
QVersionNumber(const QString &string, int *suffixIndex = nullptr)
```

in the constructors list.

I've seen this choice made in many libraries API and I cannot understand what is the advantage and why that constructor is missing.

Comment: Constructor may take more fancy arguments than you pass into that function. Those extra arguments may require some extra setup code that does not fit into constructor itself.

Comment: It makes argument more explicit, as for `static Angle Angle::FromDegree(float);`, `static Angle Angle::FromRadian(float);`.

Comment: @Jarod42: yeah, it makes sense

Comment: They can be seen as free functions and [how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

Comment: @Jarod42 not explicit enough, `static Angle Angle::From(Degree); static Angle Angle::From(Radian);`

Comment: @Jarod42 oh wow, I thought all explicits were new.

Comment: @VTT: That requires to create 2 extra types, which might not be wanted. (either type is only to create `Angle`, or it mimics mostly all functionality :-/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a great question.

The reasons will vary from scenario to scenario, but involve such concerns as:

- How readable is the constructor?
- Am I creating artificial objects or unnecessarily duplicating conditionals in order to write the constructor in terms of an initialiser list?
- Could my constructor have an ambiguity with a constructor meant to perform a different kind of construction?
- Is it obvious what my constructor is doing without having to spell out a name in code?

All of the above will involve some degree of subjectivity.

hypothetical example, guessing at the internals of a QVersionNumber,

How would you write this in terms on an initialisation list?

```
QVersionNumber 
QVersionNumber::fromString(const QString &string, int *suffixIndex)
{
    std::optional<QVersionNumber> result;
    auto first = string.begin();
    auto last = string.end();
    auto opt_major = maybe_extract_decimal(first, last); // modifies first
    if (not opt_major.has_value())
        result.emplace();
    else
    {
        auto opt_minor = maybe_extract_decimal(first, last); // modifies first
        if (not opt_major.has_value())
            result.emplace(*opt_major);
        else
            result.emplace(*opt_minor);
    }
    if (suffixIndex)
      *suffixIndex = int(std::difference(string.begin(), first);
    return *std::move(result);
}
```

It's certainly possible, deferring to a private constructor which takes a specialised function object. But the author of the library may have taken the view that this is too cryptic or difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Static creating methods are convenient because they do not require the redundant objects creation and can be added to the code of the object which they creates.There are many reasons to use creational method insteed constructor. Here are just a few:

1. The constructor must always be completed with the valid object creation. Using an exception in the constructor is a very bad practice. What can we do if the object creation  is impossible, for example due to incorrect arguments or incorrect initialization order? In the case of a creational method, you can simply return `nullptr` or some "wrong" object type.
2. If we want to customize the object creation without changing its code. For example, we want to build an object and configure it, or we don't have constructor for available arguments. The wrapper function allows you to solve the problem without touching the class code. This applies to the given example, [as you can see](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qversionnumber.cpp.html#472), `fromString` parse string argument before constructor call.
3. We do not know what kind of object to construct. This is decided at run-time. In general, we can return the base object, and choose necessary class inside the wrapper. This allows you to not change the main code for concrete object selection.
4. We want to control the creation of all objects to eliminate possible memory leaks. For example, when deinitializing a library, release all resources, even if the user forgot to do it.

I recommend you to familiarize with the design patterns, especially with [сreational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern).

Comment: For 1. Factory return object directly, so `nullptr` is not possible, and exception is fine anyway.

Comment: @Jarod42, Yes, but as I undersdand the API provides separate constructor to create a "null version" of the object, so the `fromString` function uses constructor from integer list if the sting can be parsed, or  `QVersionNumber()` in other case. This is quite relevant to point 1 and also to point  2.

Comment: Number 3 is wrong. In the example above the function returns not a pointer-to but a flat object. Try to do polymorphy and you get yourself some nice slicing. Point 4 doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @bitmask, How did you decide that all items listed refer to the author's example? I have listed the general reasons why it is used in the API. In the author case  I think it is about p2.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka: Forwarding to other constructors would also be possible with regular constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42, you're right. I looked through the code, and the most surprising thing is that none of the points fit. The function does not throw exceptions, don't implement any сreational pattern. I do not see any logical reason to use the factory method here.